# How do I prove that U(21) is isomorphic to the direct sum of Z6 and Z2?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Mainly, I'm trying to figure out if I need to just write out a specific isomorphism that defines what each element of U(21) maps to in the direct sum, or if there is some general function that will work.

Comment: Rod's answer is the way to go. However, it is a little involved if you are learning abstract algebra for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make a map just observe the following.

$U(21) = \mathbb{Z}_{21}^{\times}$

$21 = 7 \cdot 3$ and $gcd(7,3) = 1$

$\mathbb{Z}_{21}^{\times}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{\times} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3}^{\times}$

$\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{21}^{\times}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{\times} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3}^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$